# EmberJS sort Array Controller of Objects

Tags: arrays, sorting, ember.js, handlebars.js

Trying to figure this concept out. If you console.log this.get("content") before and after the sort, everything seems like it worked, but when it displays to the screen it gets funky. I think the issue is with Handlebars. When it "sorts" it adds a duplicate fourth record and sticks it at the top. You can see the problem in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/skinneejoe/Qpkz5/78/ (Click the 'Sort by Age' text a couple times to resort the records and you'll see the issues)

Am I doing something wrong, is there a better way, or is this a bug? If it's a bug is there a good workaround?

Here's the full code:

index.html

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.SortView}}Sort by Age{{/view}}<br/>

    {{#each App.userController}}
        {{#view App.RecordView contentBinding="this"}}
            {{content.name}} - {{content.age}}
        {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
    </script>
```

app.js

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.userController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
        Ember.Object.create({ name:"Jeff", age:24 }),
        Ember.Object.create({ name:"Mark", age:32 }),
        Ember.Object.create({ name:"Jim", age:12 })
    ],
    sort:"desc",
    sortContent:function() {

        if (this.get("sort") == "desc") {
            this.set("sort", "asc");
        } else {
            this.set("sort","desc")
        }

        if (this.get("sort") == "asc") {
            var sortedContent = this.get("content").sort( function(a,b){
                return a.get("age") - b.get("age");
            })
        } else {
            var sortedContent = this.get("content").sort( function(a,b){
                return b.get("age") - a.get("age");
            })
        }

        this.set("content", []);
        this.set("content",sortedContent)
    }
})

App.RecordView = Ember.View.extend({})

App.SortView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function() {
        App.userController.sortContent("poId")
    }
})
```

Comment: So what's the issue? I'm not seeing anything wrong when I click on the sort view.

Comment: When it "sorts" it adds a duplicate fourth record and sticks it at the top. Sorry I should have said that initiallly. I added it to my first post.

Comment: Which browser and version are you running? I'm on Chrome 17.0.963.56 on OSX and I'm not seeing this fourth record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing this bug in Safari, Chrome or Firefox on OS X, so I assume it's a IE issue.

Sounds a lot like [this reported Ember bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/487), which got fixed 11 days ago. Try upgrading to [ember-latest](https://github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: This solved it. I should have tried in another browser. Thanks for your help!