# Emberjs: sorting duplicates existing content

Tags: ember.js

Here is a jsfiddle for the question:

http://jsfiddle.net/stargazer/a46nj/

Clicking the insert button creates an object which has a name of 'Freyda', and inserts it into the App.Dummy. However you will see that after the sorting, the page just duplicates Tom(4). It seems it is only occuring on the level of the view part: if you examine your console, you will see that the content is sorted as intended.

There was a similar question with this: [EmberJS sort Array Controller of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365166/emberjs-sort-array-controller-of-objects). Though the problem is not precisely same, one of the comments on that post said that related bug was corrected so trying latest version would solve the problem. However in my case latest version does not help.

I need it to sort the content automatically when a new object is pushed. Is there a better way or workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove App.Dummy.arrayDidChange, see http://jsfiddle.net/a46nj/3/

Comment: I used `arrayDidChange` function because I wanted it to sort the content automatically when a new object was pushed. It seems my question was vague. I need to sort the content when a new object is inserted. As the sorting part is in the function, just removing it alone won't solve the problem.